# i try ngmodel data inside a table and didn't work

Tags: angular

I need some help with my problem. So my problem is I can't put ngmodel inside a table and do a POST to my backend. Every time I try to save the data, the ngmodel is called but the result is none.

HTML :

```
<sb-layout-dashboard [title]="'Employee'" [hideBreadcrumbs]="false"
>
<sb-card
    >

    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="btnNav">
        <button class="btn btn-primary float-right "  style="margin-left: 10px;"  (click)="saveThis()">Save Data</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary float-right" (click)="fileInput.click()">Import Excel</button>
        <input type="file" style="display:none" (change)="onFileSelected($event)" accept=".csv, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel" #fileInput>
      </div>
        <table style="width: 100%;" class="table table-bordered">
        <tr style>
          <th>No</th>
          <th style="width:100px">NIK</th>
          <th style="width:150px">Email</th>
          <th>Employee Name</th>
          <th>Corporate</th>
          <th>Card No</th>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let row of data; let i = index " ngDefaultControl>
          <td >{{i+1}}</td>
          <!-- <p [(ngModel)]="form.nik">3213213213213</p> -->
          <td [(ngModel)]="form.nik"  ngDefaultControl>{{row[0]}}</td>
          <td [(ngModel)]="form.email" ngDefaultControl>{{row[1]}}</td>
          <td [(ngModel)]="form.namalengkap" ngDefaultControl>{{row[2]}}</td>
          <td *ngIf="getCorporateName(row[3])!=false">{{ getCorporateName(row[3]) }}</td>
          <td *ngIf="getCorporateName(row[3])==false">
            <select  [(ngModel)] = "data[i][3]">
              <option value="">Pilih Corporate</option>
              <option *ngFor="let item of dataCorporate" value="{{item.corporateid}}">{{item.corporatename}}</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td [(ngModel)]="form.cardno" ngDefaultControl>{{row[4]}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
</div></sb-card
```

> 

TS :

```
form: any = {
    nik: '',
    email: '',
    fullname: '',
    aliasname: '',
    corporateid: '',
    partnerid: '',
    cardid: '',
};
```

function TS :

```
saveThis() {
    // console.log(this.form);
    this.http
        .post(serverurl.serverUrl.apinode + 'api/karyawan/addnew', { data: this.form })
        .subscribe(res => {
            console.log(res)
            console.log(this.form)
        });
}
```

this is the code guys, sorry i post pictures

Comment: Please post the code, rather than "code image".

Comment: Please update the entire code here, then only we can help you. Please use the code snippet feature to do so. Also instead of ngModel did you try angular forms? https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview

Comment: Do you know how to debug yet?  My first question is what is the value of the variable form on entry to save? P.S. past code not pictures.

Comment: oh yeah sorry guys, i edit it first. wait